# how to use mysql temporal cache tables

Tags: mysql, alter-table, cache

I took this example from a book where visitors_today is the cache table from visitor_stored. The idea is to store all the visitors per day (visitors_stored) using a cache table.

```
Create table visitors_today(
today int unsigned not null default 0,
vcount bigint unsigned not null default 0
)
engine = Innodb;

create table visitors_stored(
v_count bigint unsigned not null default 0,
vcount_date DATE not null primary key
)
engine=MyIsam;
```

My questions:

- Do I need to set up something?
- A cache table is it just a regular table, the difference is the data will be delete after update the visitors_stored?, or just because the storage engine it will be faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, your examples are just storing the `vcount` of visitors (`visitors_stored`) from today.

This means

1. You'll want a script to reset the `visitors_today` each day at midnight.
2. You'll want a trigger on `visitors_stored` to update the `visitors_today` table.

Why would you do it? If you regularly wanted to know how many visitors were from today, you would do a

```
SELECT vcount FROM visitors_today
```

instead of

```
SELECT v_count FROM visitors_stored WHERE vcount_date=NOW(); -- Probably wouldn't use NOW, but an actual static date!
```

It depends on how your server is tuned, but generally if you have an index on the `vcount_date` column in `visitors_stored`, it will suffice. If your `visitors_stored` table was overly large (>100GB say), the cache table might be of use.

If you start to see performance issues with computed columns, a cache column or table might be the way to go.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but my question is, how to use a cache table, how is it difference of a regular table?

Comment: It's all in the table definition. It's just a normal table that you query on.

Comment: so you are saying that cache tables it's just a regular table where you place the data TEMPORALLY, before to save it into the BIG table and then delete the cache table?

Comment: I'm saying as far as MySQL is concerned, based on your DDL, there is no difference in your 'cache' table and a 'BIG' table. The difference lays in how your application uses them.